# How to provide a minified template file to your minified app.js in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gulp

guyz,

I'm trying to build the angular2 for the production environment and I've generated the app.min.js using gulp and this [link](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/#). After that I've provided the inline HTML in my component file and tried to run it, its working but, how do i provide the template cache in angular2 so, that my  templateUrl in @component decorator can read and fetch the template from minified html template cache. Kindly help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would typically be done in the build process. Instead of using `templateUrl` one uses `template` and requires the HTML template as a string for that property. This way the templates are writting in the app.min.js file along with the rest. Are you using gulp or browserify? If the latter, you can use the [stringify plugin](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify) to load the templates.